# what does the .restart smali keyword do?

Tags: java, android, smali

What does this line in smali do? I have been searching for the .restart thing on google and haven't been able to find any information about it.

```
.restart local v3       #i:I
```

Comment: IMO, this shouldn't have been closed. This was a specific question about a feature of smali, which is an assembly language for dalvik bytecode. The question was clear and concise, and easily answered by someone with knowledge of dalvik bytecode/dex format, but otherwise possibly difficult to find just by searching the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to the "DBG_RESTART_LOCAL" opcode in the debug_info item in the dex file.

From http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html:

> re-introduces a local variable at the current address. The name and
>   type are the same as the last local that was live in the specified
>   register.